# Need MySQL help

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, sql

I'm having a little trouble with an sql query. Which is why I hope some of you will be able to help me.

I've got an query that selects the latest entry from each relational id but i want to select the latest where the status is different. The table looks like this.

```
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field     | Type        | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| kid_id    | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| status    | varchar(50) | NO   |     | NULL              |                |
| timestamp | timestamp   | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |                |
+-----------+-------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
```

And my current query looks like this.

```
SELECT * 
            FROM (
                SELECT * 
                FROM actions 
                AS a
                WHERE date(timestamp) = curdate() 
                AND timestamp = (
                    SELECT max(timestamp) 
                    FROM actions 
                    AS b
                    WHERE a.kid_id = b.kid_id
                    )
                )
            AS c
            ORDER BY kid_id
```

And the result looks like this:

```
id  kid_id  status  timestamp
54  1   Kommet  2010-09-15 00:14:51
57  2   Gået    2010-09-15 00:17:58
56  3   Kommet  2010-09-15 00:15:00
```

The problem is that where kid_id equals 2 I would like to see the latest entry where status = "Kommet"....

I want the 2 newest records from each kid. The first record where status = "Kommet" and the second where status = "Gået"

In advance thank you very much for your help... It's really appreciated :)

Comment: I've added the `greatest-n-per-group` tag.  This type of query has been answered dozens of times on Stack Overflow.  Go read some of the solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not to bothered about getting the id, then you could run the following:

```
SELECT kid_id, status, MAX(`timestamp`) as `timestamp`
FROM actions
WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = CURDATE()
GROUP BY kid_id, status
```

If you needed the `id`, tou couldn't just add to the `SELECT` list though, as the `GROUP BY` will pull one of the matching ids to display here, not neccessarily the one that matches the `MAX(timestamp)`.

Comment: Thank you very much this helped me alot. I did a couple of small modifications but basicly this solved my problem:)